# Cancel button on listview with asyncTask not working. due to high frequency of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask

I am developing an android application where I am downloading files using asyncTask and updating progress bar on listView from method onProgressUpdate with following code.

```
// In asynctask
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;
    try {
    fn = getFileName(aurl[0]); //working fine
    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();
    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/"+fn);
    di.title = fn;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            if(isCancelled())return (null);
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)); //publishing very very frequently as download speed is 3MBPS
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
    }
return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
   downloaditem.title = fn+" - "+progress[0]+"%";
   di.per = progress[0];
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
...
```

I have added a button on listview also to cancel this download at any time. Button click listener is as follows:

```
// In adapter holder.button is pointing to correct cancel button in listview
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       DownloadItem.di.cancel(true); // This is also correctly canceling the task
    }
});
```

The problem is as you can see `onProgressUpdate` is updating `listView` very frequently.
So I am unable to click on that button in UI to cancel it, as this button is also being refreshed very frequently.

If I make downloading slow and so the progressupdate frequency, then this works fine.

How can I handle this problem?